# How to use different overload of an inline function, depending on a compile time parameter?

Tags: c++, optimization, inline, compile-time

I have a performance critical inline function, `inline T func(T a, T b, int p)`. It can be optimized quite a bit, if p is known to be zero. However, I can't use an 'if' and penalize all the the other cases. What I want is to optimize the function only of I know at compile-time that p is zero. Is there a clean way to do that, maybe using template magic?

**EDIT**

I can't use differently named function/incompatible overloads (I don't know ho to express that correctly) since the code is very low level. It is very likely, that different optimization opportunities are available on another/future processors. Thus by confining all that low level stuff in one function signature, my code only needs to be recompiled to use any type of optimization.

Comment: If you know that p is zero at compile time, can't you simply create an overload of this function that only receives a and b as parameters and treats p as zero? This is bad because it will create some code duplication, but might be a reasonable trade off if this is performance critical and the function doesn't have too much code

Comment: @rsalmeidafl: The problem is that the optimizations are very low level, and it is possible that on another/future processor I can also optimize `p==1` case. If I can do these optimizations without additional overloads, the code needs only to be recompiled to benefit from them.

Comment: So, let me get this straight. You don't want to choose an execution path at run-time using an if, and you don't want to choose it at compile-time using an overload. How exactly *do* you intend to choose it if not at compile-time or at run-time?

Comment: @DeadMG: sorry, my mistake. I didn't formulate the edit clearly enough. What I want is to write `func(a, b, /*whatever p*/)` everywhere, and to be sure, that I can add/remove optimized overloads and all the code that uses `func` benefits from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's possible using templates. have a look at [Boost enable_if](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html), it has good explanation and usage examples

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way of doing it, if Boost doesn't satisfy. The p parameter must be a literal in the call, though.

```
#include <iostream>

// Template this on the functions if you wanted this type templated:
typedef float T; 

template<int P>
struct Wrapper {
    static T func(T a, T b) {
        std::cout << "general case (p="<< P << ")\n";
        return (a+b)*P;
    }
};

// Template specialisation for P=0
template <>
struct Wrapper<0> {
    static T func(T a, T b) {
        std::cout << "p=0 case\n";
        return 0;
    }
};

#define func(A, B, P) \
    Wrapper<P>::func(A, B)

int main() {
    func(1,2,0);
    func(1,2,345);
}
```

Template specialisation isn't possible on functions, hence the need for the wrapper class.

Answer (score 1):

GCC has a `__builtin_constant_p` function; more information in the [GCC docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.5/gcc/Other-Builtins.html). I believe you'd be able to have

```
inline T func(T a, T b, int p)
{
    if ( builtin_constant_p(p) && p==0 )
        // special case
    else
        // fallback
}
```

without any performance loss.