# How to check if a parameter of an inline function is known at compile time?

Tags: c++, static, constants, inline

I have a performance critical inline function. It generates some data, based on a parameter. I want the compiler to optimize the data generation for all invocations, where the parameter is known at compile-time. The problem is that I can't force the compiler to put the optimized data out of the stack to a static constant, since marking the data `static` would break the case when parameter is not a compile-time constant. Having constant data on the stack hurts performance. Is there a way to deduce (maybe using templates/boost::enable_if), that the parameter is a compile-time constant and choose appropriate implementation of the data generation?

**CLARIFICATION**

Basically I have something like the following:

```
struct Data {
     int d_[16];
};

inline Data fun(int param)
{  //param can sometimes be a compile-time constant

    ... //generate the data
    Data res = {gen0, gen2, gen3, ..., gen15}; //put the data into result
    return res;
}
```

So when `param` isn't compile-time constant, we just generate all the data and return.
When `param` is known, the compiler can optimize data generation out. But then it fails to optimize the following line out and generates a lot of code, that just sets `res` members to known data (the data is embedded to program code). I want the compiler to create a static constant, and then copy it to the return object (that is faster than executing much code with embedded data). Since this is an inline function, even the copy may be not necessary.

**Disclaimer**

This question is not the same as [How to use different overload of an inline function, depending on a compile time parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017629/how-to-use-different-overload-of-an-inline-function-depending-on-a-compile-time). This is more generic problem.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to detect if a function parameter is a compile time constant, and I don't see why you renamed the old question so the title contradicts the question and started a new one on this.

Comment: No, the new title doesn't contradict the question. I expressed myself incorrectly in the edit and didn't recognize that until now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not portable, but on GCC and possibly Clang there is a [`__builtin_constant_p`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) compiler function. This lets you ask the compiler if it knows the value of a variable during compile time. You can use it like this:

```
void f(int arg) {
  if (__builtin_constant_p(arg) && arg == 0) {
    // Handle case where arg is 0 AND known at compile time.
  } else {
    // Generic code.
  }
}
```

With this, the compiler will not generate the code in the `else` branch if `arg` is both known at compile time and is 0.

A useful trick to make this more portable might be to use a bit of macro hackery.

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#  define CONSTANT_P(x) __builtin_constant_p(x)
#else
#  define CONSTANT_P(x) 0
#endif
```

Add other compilers that support something similar to this as needed and you are now able to use this with no extra overhead on compilers that don't support this. That is those compilers, if they are worth anything at all, will eliminate the `CONSTANT_P` branches leaving only the generic code.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is any way to do that; it's the compiler's responsibility to optimize the calls, not the language's... so there's no portable way to do that. :\

Answer (score 1):

So it sounds like you have:

```
template <int N> myfunc_const_N() { /*...*/ }
inline myfunc_var_N(int N);
```

and you want to be able to type `myfunc(n);` and have the compiler call `myfunc_const_N<n>();` if valid or `myfunc_var_N(n);` if not?

My guess is this impossible, but that's a difficult thing to prove.

But would it really gain you much if you could?  How often do you *not* know at code-writing time whether a given expression is a compile-time constant or not?  Why not just use the template version yourself if you do have a constant and the function parameter version if you don't?

Comment: The situation can arise frequently with embedded systems.  For example, on some ST micros, some port registers map pin 0 to bit 0, pin 1 to bit 1, pin 2 to bit 2, etc.  Others map pin 0 to bits 0-1, pin 1 to bits 2-3, pin 2 to bits 4-5, etc.  If one wants to perform an operation on a set of I/O pins defined by a mask computed with 'pin n=bit n' mask, one may have to generate a mask with the bits "spread out".  If the mask is a constant, the best way to code the expansion an expression which evaluates as a compile-time constant.  If the mask isn't constant, though, the...

Comment: ...code required to evaluate the expression would be really horrible and one would be better off calling a function call to do the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

If the function is inlined, then the compiler *will* perform constant folding optimizations where appropriate, when it inlines the function, assuming that you have a fairly reasonable compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Did you actually profile your code and prove that passing constants to your (inline?) function(s) is the bottleneck?

If you did do the profiling, then you're going to have to help the compiler figure this one out, as there's no way to do it automatically. You'll have to manually call the template version of the function when you know the constant and the normal version otherwise.

Comment: The optimized function is faster by as much as 20% (entire function, not the loading phase). It seems that if large constants are embedded into code as immediates (see my edit), the entire constant will be regenerated each time, even if I don't need all the data.